# How to define image 'Save As' size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I've got a page that builds a QR Code in the Canvas element at 256X256. The assigns the source of a corresponding 'blank' image tag to it's content with a canvas toDataURL() call.

The client wants the image to be 156X156px when they save it to their machine. However when you right click to save as it saves it using the natural resolution (256X256) of the image and not the one defined the by Image tag.

How do I scale it down or force the browser to save it at certain dimensions using JavaScript?

Setting the width or height of the canvas just before I make it a URL seems to break the canvas and the image comes out as just white space.

Comment: not my area of expertise but i would hate to think you can't find a small library or plugin that would help

Comment: @charlietfl It's in my back pocket, it's just hard to believe that this can't be done with canvas/js naively somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you are using a library to produce the QR code, which in case perhaps could take options to set a size of the result.

If not, you could always make a intermediate step as changing the size of the canvas *afterwards* will clear it as you discovered.

Create a new canvas the size you need:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Set resulting size:

```
canvas.width = canvas.height = 156;
```

Draw the QR image into it:

```
ctx.drawImage(qrImage, 0, 0, 156, 156);
```

And then replace the image in DOM (if it's injected) with this canvas. An additional step may be required if the browser do lot allow right-click save of the canvas:

```
var newQR = new Image();
newQR.src = canvas.toDataURL();
// insert into DOM (replacing the old if necessary)
```

**You can wrap it up in a function like this:**

(assuming square sizes only)

```js
function reduceImage(oldImage, newSize) {

  var parent = oldImage.parentNode,
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      newImage = new Image();

  canvas.width = canvas.height = newSize;
  ctx.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, newSize, newSize);

  parent.removeChild(oldImage);

  newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  parent.appendChild(newImage);
}

// -- just for demo below --
window.onload = function() {
  var oldImg = document.getElementById("oldImage"),
      btnRepl = document.getElementById("btnRepl");
  btnRepl.onclick = function() {reduceImage(oldImg, 156)}
};
```

```css
div {border: 2px solid #999}
```

```html
<button id="btnRepl">Click to reduce size</button><br>
<div><img id="oldImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/duh6Lco.jpg" crossOrigin=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `context.scale` to rescale all new content on the canvas.**

So, assuming your original canvas is 256x256, you can draw a 156x156 version of your QR like this:

```
// resize the canvas to 156x156
canvas.width=156;
canvas.height=156;

// scale all future drawings to 156x156 instead of 256x256
var scale=156/256;
context.scale(scale,scale);

// now redraw the QR just as before
// No changes in size/coordinates needed

// After drawing the QR, just export as usual
// (it will now be 156x156)
var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL();
```

**About your "white space"**: Resizing the canvas automatically clears all content on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that wraps `context` and `canvas.toDataUrl()` mentioned by markE:

http://webreflection.blogspot.ch/2010/12/100-client-side-image-resizing.html

On this site is also little demo. After you save a resized pic, you will see it is in effect as small as you have seen it on the screen, independent of how big it was before uploading.

You will find more libraries if you search for terms like "javascript client side image resizing".